# docker compose with network, connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: postgresql, docker

Hello I have the following docker setup
I have a postgres image and my container node alpine

my **docker file:**

```
#building code FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/api/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/api

WORKDIR /home/node/api

COPY ormconfig.json .env package.json yarn.* ./

USER node

RUN yarn

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

and my **docker compose file:**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  ci-api:
    build: .
    container_name: ci-api
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/api
      - /home/node/api/node_modules
    ports:
      - '${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}'
    depends_on:
      - ci-postgres
    networks:
      - ci-network
  ci-postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: ci-postgres
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=no
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ci-postgres-data:/data
    networks:
      - ci-network

volumes:
  ci-postgres-data:

networks:
  ci-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**my env file:**

```
SERVER_PORT=4000
DB_HOST=ci-postgres
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=spirit
DB_PASS=api
DB_NAME=db
```

**my ormconfig:**

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "${DB_HOST}",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "spirit",
  "password": "emasa",
  "database": "emasa_base",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": ["dist/src/entity/**/*.js"],
  "migrations": ["dist/src/migration/**/*.js"],
  "subscribers": ["dist/src/subscriber/**/*.js"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "dist/src/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "dist/src/migration",
    "subscribersDir": "dist/src/subscriber"
  }
}
```

**my package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "training",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.ts --exec ts-node",
    "build": "tsc -b",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.ts",
    "format": "eslint src/**/*.ts --fix"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.0.2",
    "eslint": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint-config-node": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server": "^2.14.1",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.14.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^15.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "type-graphql": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.25"
  }
}
```

and i get this errors:

> error An unexpected error occurred:
>   "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/express/-/express-4.17.1.tgz: connect
>   ECONNREFUSED 104.16.26.35:443".
>
> ERROR: Service 'ci-api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c yarn'
>   returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Does that error come out of the container build phase?  Is there something in your `package.json` that needs the `ormconfig.json` you copy in?  (Does `docker build .` produce the same error?)

Comment: @DavidMaze i edit the question with ornconfig and package.json.

Comment: @DavidMaze only with docker-compose up -d get this error